# Batch file to move PDF files based on date, create folder if necessary

Tags: batch-file

I'm relatively new to batch files. I can do VERY simple ones, however this next one is throwing me for a loop.

We have a program that generates PDF quotes for customers that saves in the following way...

FirstnameLastname_Estimate_MMDDYYYY-###

For example if I had a customer "John Doe" and we gave him an estimate (#239th in our system) on Christmas Eve this year it would look like this.

JohnDoe_Estimate_12242013-239.pdf

Right now it lives in a folder "C:\Estimates". What I'd like the batch file to do is look at all of the files in the "C:\Estimates" folder and automatically move the files sorted by year. So all of the 2012 estimates are put into a folder "C:\Estimates\2012", 2013 in "C:\Estimates\2013" etc.

Some of the batch files on here get me close, but no cigar. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please include code - the parts of your existing batch files that get you close, and how they fall short. In general, break the work down into small chunks and write code to perform a single chunk properly, and then combine the parts. Also: does it HAVE to be a batch file? Batch files are typically neither robust *nor* easy to use for anything halfway complicated, compared to other scripting languages such as python or ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Launch this in the `C:\Estimates` folder. Filenames should not have `_` or `-` in the client name.

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
   for /f "tokens=3 delims=_-" %%b in ("%%a") do (
    set variable=%%b
       setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
         set variable=!variable:~-4!
         md !variable! 2>nul
         move "*!variable!-*.pdf" !variable! >nul
       endlocal
  )
)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `if exist` here? The outer `for` wouldn't return non-existing entries, so why test them for existence?

Comment: I think I got the delayed expansion right.   The `if exist` is needed I think because the `for /f` gathers all the filenames before starting, and in the loop the `move` command removes more than just the filename in `%%a` so subsequent filenames in `%%a` wouldn't be found.

Comment: Do you think it would make more sense to move the `if` so that the inner loop is omitted too when the file doesn't exist? It seems to me it should be fine and that would probably give you a tiny boost in performance. On a different note, `endlocal` doesn't need an argument (it's just `endlocal`), but it may be a good idea to put a `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` at the beginning of the script, just to make sure the `!` aren't going to be unnecessarily consumed.

Comment: @AndriyM Now that you mention it - the outer `for` **is** the loop that is passing the individual files to the `for /f` so many the `if exist` isn't needed.  I'm not sure, but it won't hurt here so I'll leave it in.